# Blank popup with FB connect

Tags: facebook, oauth

I've implemented the facebook connect using Javascript SDK. The authentication works fine when the user I'm trying to authenticate is not logged into facebook. But when he's already logged into facebook the login popup never closes. The url of the popup starts with "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect/xd_proxy.php#cb=....."

This happens both on Firefox 3.5 and on Chrome.
Any suggestions? Do I need to set any extra parameters while connecting to Facebook?

Comment: did you get a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same error today, with my year old implementation. I've added the channelUrl tag to FB.Init(), without any luck; so I started the login procedure from scratch with the js sdk, oauth2 enabled: with some minor changes, everything started to work misteriously again. I've run my pages through the Facebook debug tool as well, it suggested some changes as well.

To sum up: basically, if Facebook Connect stops working, upgrade your code according to the latest documentation avaliable.

Answer (score -1):

No special parameters are needed. This is probably a browser problem. Maybe you have a setting/plugin somewhere that does not allow Javascript to close a window for you.

The easiest way to test this is to post a link to your implementation so that other people (with other browser setups) can give it a try.